# Store serviceAccountKey.json file in third party server

Tags: firebase-admin

I have an android app which gets its data from firebase realtime database. For updating the realtime database automatically, I've written a python script which crawls data from a website and processes it. Then it sends the data to my firebase realtime database using the admin sdk. I am willing to store and execute the script on my server, so that it is executed automatically twice a day. Is it safe to upload my serviceAccountKey.json along with it? If it is not, then how can I achieve my desired functionality?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is fine to store the service account JSON file in your own server. That's the intended use case. Just make sure it's not exposed to users in anyway.